# How to remove unwanted files (like meta data) from Git branch on github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I created a branch on local repository and added some new java files. 
I used the following command to add my source code to local branch.

`git add --all`

This actually added some unwanted metadata files from Eclipse, like,
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.resources/.history/7e

I committed my changes to head using the following command:

```
 git commit -m "Commit message"
```

Pushed the branch to my remote repository using -

```
 git push origin <branchname>
```

I  realized that, I added unwanted files to my remote branch and want to remove some of them that are not actual source files.

How can I remove them from git branch without messing up my java files.

[screenshot of unwantedfiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivyI2.jpg)

Thanks much
Appreciate for the response

Answer (score 10):

`git rm` removes files from the git index, which you can then use to commit to git.  In your case, you would want the `--cached` option, which leaves the files in the working directory.

```
git rm --cached -r .metadata
git commit -am "Removing metadata"
```

You should also create or update your .gitignore file so that, once the files are removed from git, they don't accidentally get added back in.

Comment: doing now. in few minutes will post.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This will ignore the unwanted files for future commits, but they will still exist in your previous commit history.

You want to add a .gitignore file.

You can read more [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/). The further reading section provides more detail and examples if needed.

An example .gitignore for eclipse can be found [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Eclipse.gitignore).

If you choose to use the example gitignore, simply rename it to .gitignore (taking out the Eclipse prefix) and place it into your main repository folder. Then, add the file to your local branch and commit it.

---

Update:
To remove the files that have already been committed, you can do as Paul Hicks answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37474658/5776658).

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: This won't help. This avoids adding files to the repo initially.  It doesn't help remove files that are already there.

Comment: That's correct Paul, I'll clarify my answer. Thanks.